# How can this json code shows one by one line?

Tags: arrays, json

### This is my code.

```
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var myObj, i, j, x, l = "";
myObj = {
    "grids": [
        {"players": 
            [   {"duration": 404.9654235839844,"name": "Sam"},
                {"duration": 402.9412536621094,"name": "Tom"},
            ],
         "grid": "A1"
        },
        {"players": 
            [   {"duration": 433.0709228515625,"name": "Mary"},
                {"duration": 430.56573486328125,"name": "Peter"},
            ],
        "grid": "A2"
        }
     ]}

for (i in myObj.grids) {
  x += "<h2>" + myObj.grids[i].grid + "</h2>";
  for (j in myObj.grids[i].players) {
        for (l in myObj.grids[i].players[j].name) {
            x += myObj.grids[i].players[j].name[l] + "<br>";
        }
    }
}

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
</script>
```

---

Now this code will shows "name" letters in every line.
How to make it as "Sam" one line, "Tom" one line ?

Now it shows like these:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
for (i in myObj.grids) {
  x += "<h2>" + myObj.grids[i].grid + "</h2>";
  for (j in myObj.grids[i].players) {
        if (myObj.grids[i].players[j].name != "undefined") {
            x += myObj.grids[i].players[j].name + "<br/>";   
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Although your answer may be correct, it would help to add a sentence or two explaining what was wrong in OP's code and what's right about yours.

Comment: thank you for your comment.

but this will make "name" repeat few times.

my friend told me to write code like this:
-----------------------
for (i in myObj.grids) {
  x += "<h2>" + myObj.grids[i].grid + "</h2>";
  for (j in myObj.grids[i].players) {
          x += myObj.grids[i].players[j].name + "<br>";
    }
}
-------------------------------------

but....
there still one more issue...

at the first line it shows : "undefined".
dont know what something undefined....

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with this:

```
var myObj, i, j, x = "", l = "";
myObj = {
    "grids": [
        {"players": 
            [   {"duration": 404.9654235839844,"name": "Sam"},
                {"duration": 402.9412536621094,"name": "Tom"},
            ],
         "grid": "A1"
        },
        {"players": 
            [   {"duration": 433.0709228515625,"name": "Mary"},
                {"duration": 430.56573486328125,"name": "Peter"},
            ],
        "grid": "A2"
        }
     ]}

for (i in myObj.grids) {
  x += "<h2>" + myObj.grids[i].grid + "</h2>";
  for (j in myObj.grids[i].players) {
            x += myObj.grids[i].players[j].name + "<br>";
    }
}
```